# Ionic tabs not working with v-on:click with vue

Tags: ionic-framework, vue.js, ionic4

I am trying to use Ionic 4 with vue. What I want to achieve is change page upon changing tab. Here is what template is like ,

```
        <ion-tabs>
            <ion-tab label="Home" icon="home" name="home" @click="page('home')">
            </ion-tab>
            <ion-tab label="Contact" icon="contacts" name="contact" @click="page('contact')">
            </ion-tab>
            <ion-tab></ion-tab>
            <ion-tab label="Geo" icon="pin" name="geo">
            </ion-tab>
            <ion-tab label="Shake" icon="person" name="shake" @click="page('contact')">
            </ion-tab>
        </ion-tabs>
```

And in my script ,

```
<script>
  export default {
  name : 'Page',
  methods: {
    page(str) {
        this.$router.push('/'+str);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And it's not working. I am using '@ionic/vue' package.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
page (str) {
    this.$router.push({path: `/${str}`})
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers.But I found out the reason @click wasn't working is because of the <ion-tab> component itself. I have to change to <ion-tab-button> in order to work with click event. But that component doesn't seem to work in this version.